# Close the quotation

Tags: grammar

How can i tell a client that we are going to close the quotation sent to them. 
Is the term 'close the quotation' correct in this context? In fact, I need to ask them if we can **close** (cancel) the quote. 
please help.

Comment: Do you mean a price quoted for some work? If so, _expire_ would probably be better than _close_. _"The quote will expire"_.

Comment: yes, price quoted for an item, in fact. i also need to ask them if we can close (cancel) the quote.

Comment: Please can you edit that information into the question to clarify it.

Comment: Have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are issuing a quotation for the cost of a piece of work or purchasing an item, you can describe the cancellation of the quoted price differently, depending on how it will be cancelled.

If the quoted price has a time limit (e.g. the price will change in 2 days), then you can say that the quote **"will expire"** or **"has expired"**.

If you have changed your mind and do not want to offer the quote any more at all (not because of a time limit), then you are **withdrawing** the quote or **cancelling** the quote.

It is not idiomatic to say that you are *closing* the quote.

Comment: OK good. Thank you for this answer. i understand i can use 'cancelling the quote'.